# Watch a class getter in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3

#### The problem

I can't make my page auto update when there is new data. I use Ionic. I have a page that holds all items collected by the user and shows them nicely with an `ion-grid`.
To do that, I use a `v-for` and just create a col for each element:

```html
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="ion-justify-content-around">
        <ion-col v-for="item in collected" :key="item" size="5.5" @click="openDetails(item)">
            <div class="img-card">
                <img :id="`user-photo-${item.id}-${item.dType}`" :src="getSourcePhoto(item.id, item.dType)"/>
                <div class="title-holder">
                    <p>{{ formatTitle(getDiscovery(item.id, item.dType)) }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

`collected` is a list containing the user's items and is sent like so:

```js
import { UserData } from '@/internal/databases/UserData';
// And other imports

export default {
    components: {
        IonPage, IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent, IonGrid, IonRow, IonCol, IonIcon
    },

    data() {
        return {
            collected: UserData.getCollectedChronologically(),
            getDiscovery: Utils.getDiscovery,
        }
    },

    /* ... etc. */
}
```

But when the user adds a new item, the page doesn't update since it's already been cached. The item gets pushed into `UserData.data.collected.chronologically` and you need to reopen the app to see your new item show up.

#### What I tried

I tried watching the method but it obviously doesn't work:

```js
watch: {
    'UserData.getCollectedChronologically'() {
        console.log("Fired!");
        this.$forceUpdate();
    }
}
```

I also tried making a public attribute `UserData.collectedCount` and used the same watcher with that but I have the same result. I'm aware about Vuex but sadly it is not an option. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like XY problem. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unclear what's your case. You can't watch on getCollectedChronologically. It's totally unnessary to use Vuex. But you should use reactive state in such case

Comment: What happens when users add a new item? Is it added to the same array initially returned from `UserData.getCollectedChronologically()`? I think you have to make sure that it goes to the exact same array, either by managing data in a parent component and passing in updated version, or working on a global reference, possibly with support from a store. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
<ion-grid :key="ikey">

</ion-grid>

data() {
   return {
       ikey: 0,
       //....
   };
},

watch: {
   recschanged: function () {
      this.ikey++;
   },
   
computed: {
   recschanged() {
      return this.$store.getters.getAkinRecsAdder;
   },   
   
 
STORE.js
-----------------
getters: {
   getAkinRecsAdder: (state) => {
      return state.akinRecsAdder;
   },


mutations: {   
   mut_akinRecsAdder(state, aval) {
      state.akinRecsAdder = state.akinRecsAdder + aval;
   },
   
actions: {   
   setAkinRecsAdder({ commit }, aval) {
      commit('mut_akinRecsAdder', aval);
   },
```

The logic behind this is:
In store's state there is the variable akinRecsAdder
Every time the lenth of the records changed you
have to change that value.

In the component a computed property computes that value
The watch, watches this computed value and when "Fires"
increment the local data => ikey++
The ikey must be the key at `<ion-grid :key="ikey">`
and when changed forces rendering the component